# Android Emulator stops while pressing buttons on device Frame

Tags: android, android-studio, emulator

I've created an AVD and trying to change it's setting for **OpenGL ES 3.0**,   but whenever I press any of the buttons appearing on the side frame, it exits throwing the following error

```
Emulator: [24497:24497:1103/181158.243196:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using the latest version of Android Studio on Ubuntu 19.10 and API 28 for creating AVD. I am not finding any of the solutions for it. Please help me figure this out.
  It would really be a great help. An exception occurs after pressing any of these buttons

[image]

Comment: Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Comment: @DavidPostill that link defines the problem regarding chromium browser

Comment: Yes, but it's the same error you have

Comment: yeah. It isn't working while running with --no-sandbox too. That error is relevant to the Chromium browser. How can the solution be the same for both tools?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to disable sandbox and fix this issue by setting environment variable: QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX to 1:

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
```

See also same issue on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60060618/3197518